# Dictionaries and Big Inputs on Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a big input 20Gb text file which I process. I create an index which I store in a dict. Problem is that I access this dict for every term inside the file plus for every term I may add it as an item to the dict, so I can not just write it to the disk. When I reach my maximum RAM capacity (8gb ram) the system (win8 64-bit) starts paging to virtual memory so I/O is extremely high and system is unstable (I got blue screen 1 time). Any idea how can I improve it ?

---

**edit for example psedocode**

```
input = open("C:\\input.txt",'r').read()
text = input.split()
temp_dict = {}
for i,word in text:
    if word in temp_dict :
      text[i] = something()          
    else:
      temp_dict[word] = hash_function()

print(temp_dict , file=...)
print(text, file=...)
```

Comment: Can you give some example code of what you're looking to do exactly?

Comment: I have no idea what your code looks like but loading 20 gigs of data into memory is a bad idea. Why don't you create an IO system that handles and takes care of what parts of the data need to be in memory and which parts don't.

Comment: 20 Gigs? And you're loading that where? Not RAM?

Answer (score 1):

Don't read the entire file into memory, you should do something like this:

```
with open("/input.txt",'rU') as file:
    index_dict = {}
    for line in file:
        for word in line.split()
            index_dict.setdefault(word, []).append(file.tell() + line.find(word))
```

To break it down, open the file with a context manager so that if you get an error, it automatically closes the file for you. I also changed the path to work on Unix, and added the U flag for Universal readline mode.

```
with open("/input.txt",'rU') as file:
```

Since semantically, an index is a list of words keyed to their location, I'm changing the dict to index_dict:

```
    index_dict = {}
```

Using the file object directly as an iterator prevents you from reading the entire file into memory:

```
    for line in file:
```

Then we can split the line and iterate by word:

```
        for word in line.split()
```

and using the dict.setdefault method, we'll put the location of the word in an empty list if the key isn't already there, but if it is there, we just append it to the list already there:

```
            index_dict.setdefault(word, []).append(file.tell() + line.find(word))
```

Does that help?

Comment: Every item inside the dict is needed for the lookups, so I do not know how this will help me

Comment: I hadn't yet solved that when I posted, but I think I now have, how's that?

Comment: I will give it a try. I anticipate that the script for this input(20gb) will take 14~20 hours to execute.

Comment: I hope it won't take that long, but let me know how it goes. Perhaps you should make a much smaller demo file for a faster iteration cycle.

Comment: Well I had, it was my test input, 5mb, took like 0.5 seconds. In my algorithm I try to compress Inverted Files, so I have to try the big data now.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend simply using a database instead of a dictionary. In its simplest form, a database is a disk-based datastructure which are meant to span several gigabytes.

You can have a look at [sqlite3](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) or [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) for instance.

Additionally, you probably don't want to load the whole input file in memory at once either.